# How to make ImageView reappear after making it null

Tags: java, android, xml, imageview

I am using an ImageView in a webView for android and I am struggling to make it appear and disappear when I want it to. I have tried setting the visibility to GONE and VISABLE but that doesn't seem to work with the way that I am using it. I then researched a bit and found that the following code works to make the ImageView disapeare:

```
imgView.setImageDrawable(null);
```

or

```
imgView.setImageResource(android.R.color.transparent);
```

But the only problem with this is that once it disappears it doesn't appear again and seems like it is permanently gone even if I use setVisability(View.VISABLE). Does anyone know how to make the ImageView appear again?

Any assistance would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said that setting the visibility to GONE or VISIBLE did not solve your problem, then how about setting it to INVISIBLE?

INVISIBLE means that the view is physically invisible but other views think it is still there. As such, other views will be laid out as if the view is visible.

If this doesn't solve it either, try this:

- get the image in the image view by calling `getDrawable`.
- store the image somewhere, such as in a field, so that you can access it later.
- call `setImageDrawable(null)` when you want to hide the image view
- call `setImageDrawable(yourImage)` when you want to show the image view again. `yourImage` is the drawable you got from `getDrawable` from before.

Answer (score 1):

How about reset a visible resource on your `imgView`. Such as

```
imgView.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void showImage(){ 
   imgView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

private void hideImage(){
   //with imageView`s space
   imgView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
   //with no space
   imgView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Comment: Add some descriptions / explanation to your answer, it will help others to understand better.

Answer (score 0):

**use this code it's web client which handle web view page start and finish process:**

webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

```
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            imgview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });
```